# Error while running "npm run watch" in larvael 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, laravel-8

when I run "npm run watch" This is what i am getting. 
This is a fresh laravel 8 project. 
I have just used the Auth package.

**Here's The componentr:-**

```
<template>
    
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-4">
        <div class="card card-default">
            <div class="card-header">
                Task Form
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="./api/task" method="POST" onclick="addTask()">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Task title" class="form-control">

                        
                    </div>
                    <input type="submt" value="Add Task" class="btn btn-info">
                </form>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
</template>

<script >
    
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('component mounted.')
        },

        methods: {
            addTask(){
                alert('Adding The Task');
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Here's the app.js file:-**

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('task-form', require('./components/Task.vue'));

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

I couldn't post the whole eror as it was too long, I hope this is enough to understand

**Here's The Error:-**

```
kabir@kabir-pc:~/Desktop/Vue$ npm run watch

> @ watch /home/kabir/Desktop/Vue
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development /home/kabir/Desktop/Vue
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
webpack is watching the files…

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 9863ms                                                                                                      3:59:13 pm

       Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css   178 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
  /js/app.js  1.41 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/cancel'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/core): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/core'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/vendor): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/vendor'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/css-loader/lib): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/css-loader/lib'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/jquery/dist): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/jquery/webpack/buildin/global.js'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/webpack/buildin): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/webpack/buildin): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/webpack/buildin): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/node_modules/webpack/buildin/system.js'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js/app.js'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js/bootstrap.js'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js/components): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js/components): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/js/components/Task.vue'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/sass): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/sass/_variables.scss'
Error from chokidar (/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/sass): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/kabir/Desktop/Vue/resources/sass/app.scss'
```

I don't know what else to type as stackoverflow is not asking for more description about this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use below command, it will work

```
npm run watch-poll
```

Comment: Thanks buddy It worked. Can you explain me how and why, I'll accept the answer later as its not allowing me right now

Comment: Sure @AnonymousChatbox, once you are allowed to accept then accept my answer.

Comment: Basically npm run watch not check changes inside your project directly in run time but watch-poll periodically checks (polls) for changes e.g. every 1000ms it will manually check to see if any files have changed.

Comment: `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` this solved the problem too, now i can use `npm run watch`

Comment: ok sure, Thanks but question already closed.